# THD and SNR of XMega32 family microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, noise, atmega

I am trying to figure out the noise (voltage) introduced by the internal ADC of the ATXmega32E5 in terms of SINAD, and therefore using SNR and THD. By analyzing the datasheet of the above mentioned device, I am able to determine the INL and DNL characteristics of the device. However, despite the relationship existing at low frequencies between INL and THD, I cannot find a reference that clearly provides these parameters or a way to derive them from the data presented in the datasheet. Could you kindly help me?